# call Child LWC from Parent LWC through Button

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to call a Child LWC from a Parent LWC through a button, But child component gets displayed along with the parent component.

```
<template>
<div style="height: 300px;" >
     <div>  
        <c-new-acre-comp></c-new-acre-comp>
        <lightning-button label="New Acre" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-float--right">
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
```

and passing my component through the query selector in the **handleClick** method in JS.

```
this.template.querySelector('c-new-acre-comp').handleValueChange();
```

Can someone suggest, what I am missing here?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], and take the [tour] to get an idea of what good questions should look like. Then, [edit] your question to include additional information, such as what you're trying to accomplish and what challenges you're facing. As it is, I have no idea what you're asking for or how to help you.

Comment: <template>
<div style="height: 300px;" >
 <div>  
<c-new-acre-comp></c-new-acre-comp>
 <lightning-button label="New Acre" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-float--right">
 </lightning-button>
</div>
</div>
        <div>
           <template if:true={seededAcres.data}>
            
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={Acres.data}
                show-row-number-column
                row-number-offset={rowOffset}

Comment: I am trying to call the child component through a button in the Parent Component.

Comment: What does it mean to "call the child component"? Are you trying to display it? Call a method in it? Pass data into it?

Comment: I am trying to display the child component through a button in the parent component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how you can [Render DOM Elements Conditionally](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_conditional) in Lightning Web Component.

> To render HTML conditionally, add the if:true|false directive to a
>   nested  tag that encloses the conditional content.
>
> The if:true|false={property} directive binds data to the template and
>   removes and inserts DOM elements based on whether the data is a truthy
>   or falsy value.

In your case, You need to define a boolean property in js file and use `<template if:true={showNewAcreComponent}><c-new-acre-comp></c-new-acre-comp></template>` to conditionally show and hide in html file.Let's say, you have defined the property with name **showNewAcreComponent** having default value as false.  Whenever value of **showNewAcreComponent** property defined in js file returns true, the **c-new-acre-comp** will render on the screen. When **showNewAcreComponent** returns false, **c-new-acre-comp** will not render on the screen dynamically.

```
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <template if:true={showNewAcreComponent}>
            <c-new-acre-comp></c-new-acre-comp>
        </template>
        <lightning-button label="New Acre" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-float--right">
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
```

In your js file, we are changing the property value to true:-

```
showNewAcreComponent = false;
handleClick() {
    this.showNewAcreComponent = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sanket.